# ProFTPD server - multiple ports, same IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ftp, proftpd

I am having problems with ProFTPD server, because I am not able to set it to work correctly when multiple ports are active (IP address is the same).

In my proftpd.conf file, I have added this section:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
    Port                        2122
    Umask                       022
    ServerName                  "Example"
    DefaultRoot                 /home/usr1/www/example1
    UserAlias                   fuser usr1

    # Valid LOGINs
    <Limit LOGIN>
        AllowUser usr1
        DenyALL
    </Limit>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I try to establish connection to port 21, everything is ok, and I get directory listing. But when I try to establish connection to port 2122, it connects, but I get an error **500 Illegal PORT command** at the very end.

In Linux Firewall ports 21 and 2122 are opened.

This is what I get when execute **netstat -lpn | grep ftp**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::2122                 :::*                    LISTEN      30597/proftpd: (acc
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      30597/proftpd: (acc
```

Now, I am not sure, where could be a problem with this virtual server, and why I cannot get directory listing at the very end.

The point is, that I need two FTPs, since some of users should connect to the first one, and some of them to the second. Every FTP has its own home directory.

If needed, I can provide the full proftpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

There is passive and active mode in FTP server, for active mode you will need to open a port range. In active mode FTP server opens a random port for data transfer, then client connects to the random port. If your firewall block this port, then directory listing, and data transfer will fail.

In passive mode, client opens new port then tells the server to connect it for data transfer. Passive mode would not work with all routers, client may cannot open a port for data transer.

**Solution:** Open a port range (eg. 1500 to 2000), then configure your FTP server to use these ports.

http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html